# How can I put a file path into the clipboard so that it can be pasted as file in a file manager?

Tags: c, linux, gtk, clipboard

I want the user to be able to copy a file that's stored on disk from my GTK application to a normal file manager like Nautilus. How can I do that? I would prefer to just write a path into the clipboard and let the file manager take care of actually copying, is that possible?

I just found an example in which it seems as if the actual file data is transferred through the clipboard – but is that the only possible way?

Answer (score 1):

You need CF_HDROP and possibly other shell clipboard formats.
See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776902(v=vs.85).aspx;

Comment: Oh, sorry - forgot to mention I'm using Linux.